# Как спроектировать базу данных, если у меня два пользователя с некоторыми различными полями

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, sqlite

Программа имеет двух пользователей  **doctor** и **patient** которые обладают некоторыми  *общими полями*.
Я создал  **таблицу user** в котором будут *общие поля пользователей*.

(*id, name, surname, age, city, country, usertype*)

Но пользователь **doctor** имеет *дополнительные поля* присущие только ему

(*experience, biography, address*).

Kак создать таблицу *для не общих полей* **пользователя doctor** и как *соединить эту таблицу* с **таблицей user**.

Comment: А в чем проблема? Вы же описали все, связывайте по Id. Если тип доктор, то выборку делайте из двух таблиц

Comment: Не надо, оставь всё в одной таблице. С двумя намучаешься, уж лучше разреженная, но одна. Я уж и не говорю о случае, когдла один doctor обратится к другому как patient...

Comment: @Akina Не учите человека плохому, это ведь будет не расширяемо.

Comment: Могу порекомендовать почитать про отношения таблиц и внешние ключи [вот здесь, например](http://zametkinapolyah.ru/zametki-o-mysql/chast-11-4-vneshnie-klyuchi-v-bazax-dannyx-sqlite-foreign-key-v-sqlite3.html)

Comment: @Klimenkomud насчёт не-расширяемости - совсем не понял...

Comment: @Akina А если в систему добавится новый тип юзера? А если у доктора появятся новые свойства? Если у пациента добавятся новые свойства? Добавлять колонки в таблицу `user`? И в конечном итоге таблица будет иметь овер 9000 колонок, и большая половина - пустая. И всё это дело будет сьедать место на диске и влиять на скорость обработки запросов к этой заблице. Плюс, без `ORM` создание новых юзеров превратится в сущий ад.

Comment: @Klimenkomud Учите матчасть, Akina все правильно говорит. `"А если в систему добавится новый тип юзера?"` - тогда в таблицу "тип юзера" добавится новая запись. `"А если у доктора появятся новые свойства? Если у пациента добавятся новые свойства? Добавлять колонки в таблицу user?"` Да, именно так. `"И всё это дело будет сьедать место на диске и влиять на скорость обработки запросов к этой заблице."` не будет. `"Плюс, без ORM создание новых юзеров превратится в сущий ад."` - ORM - это само по себе сущий ад, существующий исключительно потому, что кое-кому лень учить SQL.

Comment: @Dmitry, Думаю, матчасть нужно учить вам. Вы знаете что "пустота" в БД также занимает память на диске? Да ещё и зависимо от типа данных колонки - может занимать больше или меньше, но всёравно занимать. Вы знаете, что если будете фильтровать таблицу по какой-то опциональной колонке(которая может быть пустой) - БД будет искать по всем строкам? Это увеличивает время обработки запроса. Вы видели какую-либо информацию про таблицу "тип юзера" в вопросе? `ORM` существует не потому, что кому-то лень учить `SQL`, а банально потому, что если в проекте будет много запросов - прийдется писать свою `ORM`.

Comment: @Dmitry И конечно, память для диска сейчас - не особо проблема в наше время, это было очень актуально лет 10 назад, сейчас уже не так. Но всёравно, если таблица будет иметь 100000 записей - множество пустых колонок могут существенно увеличить объем занимаемой памяти на диске. Это приведет к денормализации данных, что на уровне кода даст сущий ад в разруливании вопросов вроде "этот юзер - доктор, пациент, или кто-то ещё?". И конечно это можно полечить банальной колонкой "тип юзера", а потом ещё одной, и ещё одной ... Советую вам поинтерисоваться формами нормализации БД, очень полезная инфа.

Comment: @Klimenkomud Демонстрируйте свою неграмотность в другом месте, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Dmitry Супер аргумент, вы паррировали бесподобно, больше вопросов не имею.

Answer (score 1):

С ходу в голову приходят 2 варианта

1. Создать две таблице user и doctor, связь между ними будет 1:1. Тоже сделать и с таблицей patient у которой будет связь с таблицей user 1:1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Использовать модель "Сущность - Атрибут - Значение" (EAV. entity-attribute-model)